# How do I plot $y=8 \sin(2 \pi / 3)$?

Tags: plotting

I'm new to sin, cos, and tan graphs. I can seem to accurately create a sin graph without the the points being incorrect. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, it is unclear what do you want to do, or that it is about Mathematica. If so, please take a look at `Plot` and let us know if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The function you want to plot is constant. So you could do something like this

```
myConstant=8 Sin[2 Pi/3];
Plot[myConstant,{z,-10,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, but perhaps what you really want to do is to plot

$\qquad y=8 \sin(2\, \pi\, x / 3)$

Plotting that will produce a curve. It can be done with

```
Plot[8 Sin[2 π x/3], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: plot]